# Get all checked checkboxes in certain div by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom asp.net control which contains some checkBoxes. I know how to get the checkBox, that was clicked

```
$('#customer-category-control input:checkbox').click(function(event)
 {   
   var el =  $(this).attr('name');
 };
```

Suggest me, please, how to get only all checked checkBoxes by click and make a JSON object from their names.

Comment: Hmm... I see all kinds of events mixed up on different elements. Why would you listen for a click event on a `checkbox`? First attach a `change` event, and when you are going to catch the `submit` event you can get a list of the checked checkboxes with `$('#customer-category-control input:checkbox:checked')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var names=[];
$('#customer-category-control input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function (i, el){
    names.push(el.name);
    });
console.log(names); // => ['foo','bar'...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var obj = [];
$('#customer-category-control input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(index, value) {
    obj.push($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

Comment: Where do you want to click? you haven't mentioned that

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function ()  
        {
           $('#customer-category-control input:checkbox').click(function(event)
               {
               var obj = [];
               $('#customer-category-control input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(index, value)
                   {  obj.push($(this).attr("name"));      });
alert(obj);

           });
        });
```